# Firebase verification code expiration time in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-authentication

How can i get expiration time of verification code sent by firebase authentication service?

I want to show a timer after requesting for verification code.

What i did try :

```
//Receiving verfication id and request for verification code
PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, uiDelegate: nil) { (verificationID, error) in
  if let error = error {
    self.showMessagePrompt(error.localizedDescription)
    return
  }
}

let credential = PhoneAuthProvider.provider().credential(
    withVerificationID: verificationID,
    verificationCode: verificationCode)

//Verify verification code
Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (authResult, error) in
  if let error = error {
    let authError = error as NSError
    return
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest first reading the [general documentation for handling errors](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/errors).  The API documentation for [signIn()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/Auth#signinwith:completion:) suggests all the possible types of error objects that could be returned.  It's not clear to me exactly which one it will be, but it should be easy to log the error you get back, and compare it to what you see in the docs.  My guess is that you will see a `FIRAuthErrorCodeInvalidCredential` ([invalidCredential](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Enums/AuthErrorCode#invalidcredential)).

Comment: Yes, I've read it but actually i want to show a timer to user, and it cant be happen without expiration  time.

Comment: OK, that sounds like a different problem.  I don't think the SDK is going to help you build that.

Comment: Yes my question wasn't clear, thanks for your response Doug.